# Why does Ubiquity not recognize an EFI System Partition which has a Windows Boot Loader in it? (aka can't reinstall Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ubiquity, reinstall

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu 19.10 + Windows 10 laptop (details below), and (UEFI) dual booting works fine.

I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu 19.10 off a live usb and Ubuiquity is throwing an error "No EFI System Partition found". However, I have an EFI partition. It looks like there may be two issues:

1. Ubiquity is classifying the ESP partition, p1, as "Windows Boot Manager" rather than as ESP. See the screenshots below. From the logs and browsing the os-prober scripts, it looks like os-prober (/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi and /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft) will not recognize an ESP partition if the  partition looks to have a microsoft bootloader in it. Does anyone know why that is?  Or how to get past the error?  Maybe the os-prober in Ubiquity isn't the problem?
2. Ubiquity does not recognize partition 3 as a Windows 10 partition. This may be because bitlocker is used on it. I'm hesitant to turn off bitlocker for fear of destabilizing the windows installation.  Right now windows and dual-boot work fine, and the original install of Ubuntu next to Windows via Ubiquity didn't have an issue.

My laptop is a Lenovo X1 6th gen, BIOS v1.46. Here's the partition table. Partition 3 is Windows 10 and partition 5 is Ubuntu 19.10.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: SAMSUNG ... (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, hidden, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   129GB  129GB                Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      129GB   255GB  126GB   ext4
 4      255GB   256GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

And some choice parts of the Efi partition file listing:

```
19:44:47 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/
'$RECYCLE.BIN'   BOOT   boot-repair   EFI  'System Volume Information'
19:44:51 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/BOOT/
BOOT.SDI
19:44:58 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/
Boot  Microsoft  ubuntu
19:45:10 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/
bkpbootx64.efi  bootx64.efi  fbx64.efi  LenovoBT.EFI  License.txt  mmx64.efi  ReadMe.txt
19:45:14 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/
Boot  Recovery
19:45:28 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/
BCD       bootmgfw.efi  da-DK  es-ES  fr-CA  ja-JP           kd_02_15b3.dll  kd_07_1415.dll  lv-LV        pt-BR      ru-RU       tr-TR
BCD.LOG   bootmgr.efi   de-DE  es-MX  fr-FR  kd_02_10df.dll  kd_02_1969.dll  kd_0C_8086.dll  memtest.efi  pt-PT      sk-SK       uk-UA
BCD.LOG1  BOOTSTAT.DAT  el-GR  et-EE  hr-HR  kd_02_10ec.dll  kd_02_19a2.dll  kdstub.dll      nb-NO        qps-ploc   sl-SI       winsipolicy.p7b
BCD.LOG2  boot.stl      en-GB  fi-FI  hu-HU  kd_02_1137.dll  kd_02_1af4.dll  ko-KR           nl-NL        Resources  sr-Latn-RS  zh-CN
bg-BG     cs-CZ         en-US  Fonts  it-IT  kd_02_14e4.dll  kd_02_8086.dll  lt-LT           pl-PL        ro-RO      sv-SE       zh-TW
19:45:23 X1-6th:~ (master)$ ls /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
BOOTX64.CSV  fw  fwupdx64.efi  fwupx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
```

I also tried boot-repair.  And here are more details on the error. When I click to reinstall Ubuntu as here:

[image: ubiquity loader showing reinstall option for 19.10]

I then get the error shown here:

[image: no efi error]

Here's what the partition map looks like as shown by Uqiquity. Note it doesn't see the EFI partition as an EFI partition, unlike parted and gparted:

[image: partition map shown by ubiquity]

And here's the same partition map shown by gparted, showing that the boot and esp flags are set on p1:

[image]

And here's a portion of the install logs from /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar 14 11:28:46 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: debconffilter_done: ubi-prepare (current: ubi-prepare)
Mar 14 11:28:46 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Step_before = stepPrepare
Mar 14 11:28:46 ubuntu activate-dmraid: No Serial ATA RAID disks detected
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  212.811940] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 31824 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  212.860012] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 22786 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  212.907942] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 32082 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  212.956017] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 19959 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.004005] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 26130 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.051940] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 18363 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.099943] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 14898 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.148005] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  9505 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.195942] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 12908 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.243943] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  8676 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.291943] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 11453 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.340016] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6568 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.340017] raid6: using algorithm avx2x2 gen() 32082 MB/s
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.340017] raid6: .... xor() 19959 MB/s, rmw enabled
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.340018] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.363707] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.434474] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.471783] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu kernel: [  213.560825] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu partman:   /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu partman:   No matching physical volumes found
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu partman:   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Mar 14 11:28:47 ubuntu partman:   /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Mar 14 11:28:48 ubuntu partman-lvm:   /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Mar 14 11:28:48 ubuntu kernel: [  214.093546]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
Mar 14 11:28:49 ubuntu systemd-resolved[1498]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 11:29:00 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[1500]: Synchronized to time server for the first time 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 14 11:29:05 ubuntu systemd-resolved[1498]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu kernel: [  236.177827]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ntfsresize: ERROR: Device '/dev/sdc1' is mounted read-write. You must 'umount' it first.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu partman: Error running 'ntfsresize --info'
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.7GxvlA6ke4: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.7GxvlA6ke4: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.7GxvlA6ke4.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp-tmp.7GxvlA6ke4.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.unAAkrHZeN: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.unAAkrHZeN: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.unAAkrHZeN.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp-tmp.unAAkrHZeN.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu kernel: [  236.882561]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ntfsresize: ERROR: Device '/dev/sdc1' is mounted read-write. You must 'umount' it first.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu partman: Error running 'ntfsresize --info'
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.Xnaqv8xLsd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.Xnaqv8xLsd: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.Xnaqv8xLsd.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.g1O8wFG11P: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.g1O8wFG11P: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp-tmp.g1O8wFG11P.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.g1O8wFG11P.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ntfsresize: ntfsresize v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ntfsresize: ERROR: Device '/dev/sdc1' is mounted read-write. You must 'umount' it first.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu partman: Error running 'ntfsresize --info'
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.TzFOm52RrH: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.TzFOm52RrH: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.TzFOm52RrH.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp-tmp.TzFOm52RrH.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.2Z1AnhHCWK: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu ubiquity: mount: /tmp/tmp.2Z1AnhHCWK: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp-tmp.2Z1AnhHCWK.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu systemd[1842]: tmp-tmp.2Z1AnhHCWK.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu kernel: [  237.574586] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
Mar 14 11:29:11 ubuntu kernel: [  237.631066] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober:   /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB fat filesystem driver
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition scheme is gpt
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition type is c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/10elilo
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 20microsoft: result: Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: bootloader Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows found by subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: result: /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: os found by subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu systemd[1842]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: os detected by /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p2 type not recognised; skipping
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: os detected by /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p3
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p3
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: creating device mapper device /dev/mapper/osprober-linux-nvme0n1p3
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounting /dev/mapper/osprober-linux-nvme0n1p3 (/dev/nvme0n1p3) as BitLocker failed: mount: /var/lib/os-prober/mount: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: remove device mapper device /dev/mapper/osprober-linux-nvme0n1p3
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p4
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p4
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB ntfs filesystem driver
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is ntfs partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 83haiku: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu systemd[1842]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB ext2 filesystem driver
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p5 is ext2 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p5 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p5 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p5 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p5 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 40lsb: result: /dev/nvme0n1p5:Ubuntu 19.10 (19.10):Ubuntu:linux
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: os found by subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu systemd[1842]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: os detected by /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda1 is iso9660 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/sda1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/sda1 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sda1 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/sda1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu 83haiku: debug: /dev/sda1 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/sda1
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/sda2
Mar 14 11:29:13 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/sda2
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB fat filesystem driver
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda2 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda2 partition scheme is dos
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda2 partition type is 0xef
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda2 is not a ESP partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/sda2 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/sda2 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sda2 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/sda2 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 83haiku: debug: /dev/sda2 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu systemd[1842]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sda3 is ext4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sda3 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 83haiku: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/sda3
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/sdc1 is fuseblk partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10freedos: debug: /dev/sdc1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 10qnx: debug: /dev/sdc1 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sdc1 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 20microsoft: debug: Skipping legacy bootloaders on UEFI system
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 30utility: debug: /dev/sdc1 is not a FAT partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu 83haiku: debug: /dev/sdc1 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/sdc1
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device free not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device /dev/nvme0n1p2 not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device /dev/nvme0n1p4 not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device free not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: Device /dev/sdc1 not found in os-prober output
Mar 14 11:29:14 ubuntu ubiquity[4336]: switched to page partman
```

The relevant part seems to be:

```
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/10zvol-test on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB fat filesystem driver
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition scheme is gpt
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition type is c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/10elilo
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 20microsoft: result: Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: debug: bootloader Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows found by subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
Mar 14 11:29:12 ubuntu 05efi: result: /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

Comment: My EFI partition has a Windows bootloader in it and Ubuntu installed just fine using that partition.

Comment: Welcome! You say *"will reject any EFI system partition"*, how do you get to that conclusion? What do the logs say?

Comment: Ubiquity only installs to first drive's ESP. It looks like it should see your NVMe drive, if you have updated firmware and drive fully seen. We have seen where chkdsk or dosfsck required on FAT32 partition due to some corruption. `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/nvme0n1p1`

Comment: @guillermochamorro: Thanks for taking a look. I added more info to the post, including the installer log messages and the section of log I think is indicative. I also based my conclusion from the source code of os-probes/mounted/05efi, which seems to suggest that if a windows boot loader is found it no longer considers a partition as an EFI partition.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks for the suggestion. The EFI partition seems fine. I can mount it, browse files in it and the grub reinstall by boot-repair worked fine. I included the output of a few ls commands in the post.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I also was able to install ubuntu without issue. My problem is that I want to reinstall it and the installer is throwing the error I mention.

Comment: Does your p1 have the boot and or esp flags. You can set flags with gparted (right click on partition) and various command line tools. Looking at guid code c12a7.....  that is the ESP. Boot flag or esp flag actually set the very long GUID code for actual use. Half way down. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Comment: @oldfred: I just added a screenshot of gparted. Yes, esp and boot flags are set on p1. Note how p1 appears differently in gparted than it does in the installer. Looking at that os-prober code I mentioned, it really looks like Ubuiquity excludes partitions that otherwise look like EFI except have a windows boot loader in them.

Comment: Just noticed you have bitlocker? I have seen that to dual boot you must turn that off. It may be locking the ESP and would prevent the installer from correctly seeing any NTFS partitions.

Comment: @oldfred, Thanks, I updated the post - looks like there are 2 possibly distinct issues - 1. ubiquity classifies p1 as a "windows boot manager" partition rather than ESP.  and 2. ubiquity does not recognize p3 as a windows partition, perhaps due to bitlocker. I'm hesitant to turn off bitlocker in fear of destabilizing my windows installation.  Ubuntu installed fine the first time and dual boot works fine. (It's the reinstall that's giving problems).